# Allow only the user who owns the data to edit it in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Here's how my database looks:

[image: Click here to see how my database looks like]

What I want is like this:

- Everyone can add and read data.
- Only the user who added the data is able to edit/delete it using his uid which already saved as a child.

I tried this, but after testing I can only add new data, but not edit or delete it as an owner of it:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false,
      
    "MOREBLOCKS":{
      ".read": true,
      "$block":{
        ".write": "(!data.exists() && newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid ) || (data.child('uid').val() == auth.uid && newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid)"
      }
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: At first glance the rule looks fine. Did you already remove one of the `||` clauses to see where the problem is? Also: how did you test that this doesn't work? If it was in code, can you edit your question to include the [minimal code with which you can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Yes, I tried your idea but no good result is seen yet. About the code, I get all the children into a listview and show them with 2 buttons, one to add new items and the other to delete current position item, no special codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tests, I came up with the following rules, I hope this may be helpful for you.

```
{
  "rules": {
  ".read": false,
  ".write": false,
      
  "MOREBLOCKS": {
  ".read": true,  
    
  "$blocks":{
  ".write": "(!data.exists() && newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid ) || (!newData.exists() && data.child('uid').val() === auth.uid) || (data.child('uid').val() == auth.uid && newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid)",
      }
    },
  }
}
```